# Platform event not getting subscribed

Tags: custom-object, platform-event, publish-subscribe

I have created a platform event with Publish Immediately behavior. It is very basic one. Once it is published, I want to upsert a custom object records. I am publishing it through developer console and subscribing through trigger (it is active) on after insert. In trigger, I am just printing the Trigger.New list. I can see in the logs, it is getting publish successfully but trigger is not getting invoked. Is there anything that I am doing wrong? Below are the details:

Platform Event:

[image: Platform event]

Publishing through Developer Console:

```
List<Test__e> testvents = new List<Test__e>();
testvents.add(new Test__e(Name__c='Test'));
// Call method to publish events
List<Database.SaveResult> results = EventBus.publish(testvents);

// Inspect publishing result for each event
for (Database.SaveResult sr : results) {
    if (sr.isSuccess()) {
        System.debug('Successfully published event. '+sr);
    } else {
        for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) {
            System.debug('Error returned: ' +
                    err.getStatusCode() +
                    ' - ' +
                    err.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Apex Trigger:

[image]

Apex Debug:

[image]

Comment: you might need to have test coverage of the trigger first; you should also query `EventBusSubscriber` to verify there are no errors

Comment: Hi @cropredy, trigger contains nothing but a system debug statement. Also can you share how would having trigger code coverage help to overcome the issue? Querying EventBusSubscriber returned the subscribing trigger.

Comment: Write a test method that does an EventBus.publish.

Comment: I did that. The test class executed successfully. Also in debug, the event got published successfully and EventBusSubscriber returned trigger and subscribing process builder records. But still trigger or the apex class I am calling from process builder is not executing.

Comment: @cropredy: updated question with more details. Please suggest if you find anything.

Comment: Unless configured otherwise, the trigger will run as Automated Process user.  Did you look at debug logs for Automated Process user?

Comment: Debugging through Automated Process user did the trick!! Thank you very much @cropredy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless configured otherwise, the Platform Event trigger will execute in the context of the Automated Process user.  Check the debug log for the Automated Process user and you'll see your trigger execute.